# Python execution certain steps in a function based on input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently , I have a function which includes steps that are common irrespective of the user input. But some steps need to be executed only for certain inputs. In the example below, (see if apples :  do something).

What are other alternate, more optimized ways of accomplishing this , as opposed to entering a boolean input for every choice?

E.g.:

```
choice = input("Select option: ")
if choice == "1":
   apple = True
   test_operation(user, apple, pear="")
elif choice == "2":
   pear = True
   test_operation(user, apple="", pear=pear)
elif choice == "3":
   test_operation(user, apple="", pear="")


def test_operation(user, apple, pear):

    if apple:
       do something
    if pear:
        do something else
    else:
        do both

    #Print results , common for all
    for category in operations:
        print(f"\n{category}")
        for task in operations[category]:
             print(f"{task}: {operations[category][task]}")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to describe in more detail what you are aiming to do.

Comment: Your `else:` is only attached to `if pear`. So it will be executed when `pear` is false, regardless of `apple`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Please post a more meaningful example, it's hard to tell what you really want from these abstract variables.

Comment: I think you are better off using switch case here.

Comment: @AllMightyGoat Python doesn't have that. And even if it did, it's not useful for testing multiple variables.

Comment: Which part of the code are you trying to simplify? the `if choice` part or the `test_operation` code?

Comment: Why don't you just pass `choice` to the function instead of multiple variables?

Comment: @Barmar welp my mistake but if choice was a perfect for switch case but sadly python doesn't support that as you said but he can use dictionary instead.

Comment: @AllMightyGoat `switch-case` is essentially a whole bunch of `if...elif`s

Comment: @Pranav  I know but I find way more convenient to use switch case than writing `if x == y` for every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can create functions for each action. Then create a dictionary where the keys are the user input and the values are lists of actions

```
def do_apple():
    # Something
def do_pear():
    # Something else

actions = {"1": [do_apple],
           "2": [do_pear],
           "3": [do_apple, do_pear] }

def test_operation(user, all_actions):
    # Call each function
    for action in all_actions:
        action()
    ...

choice = input("Select option: ")
if choice in actions:
    test_operation(user, actions[choice])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding more unnecessary variables like apples,pear just pass the variable choice to the test_operation function then process further according to the choice

```
choice = int(input("select option"))
def test_operation(choice):
  if choice == 1:
     do you stuff 
  elif choice == 2:
     some other stuff
  else:
     do both
  common stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the input and check it directly:

```py
def test_operation(user, choice):
    if choice == "1":
        # do apples
    if choice == "2":
        # do pear
    if choice == "3":
        # do both
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch construct.  Since there is no switch-statement in Python, you'll need a helper function to simulate it:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

And you could write your code like this:

```
choice = input("Select option: ")

for case in switch(choice):
    if case("1","3"):
       # perform apple test
    if case("2","3"):
       # perform pear test
```